# NameError: name 'QImage' is not defined

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, nameerror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:/QGIS/bin/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    img = QImage(QSize(800,600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
NameError: name 'QImage' is not defined
```

I encountered this error when I was trying for Map Rendering and Printing on python console given in QGIS.

Comment: missing import? Can you show a more complete example that demonstrates the problem so we don't have to guess?

Answer (score 5):

QImage is in QtGui, so my first thought would be that you need to import PyQt4.QtGui.

So either:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
```

Or:

```
import PyQt4.QtGui
```

But more information would be helpful if importing PyQt4.QtGui doesn't get rid of the error.