# QImage Not Defined

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to get a set of map images with a Python script in QGIS. I load the background raster and my csv vector file and then I try to get the image. When I start the example from the PyQGIS cookbook (http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html) I get the following error:

```
img = QImage(QSize(800, 600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<input>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'QSize' is not defined
```

I looked at a closed question [NameError: name 'QImage' is not defined](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88660/nameerror-name-qimage-is-not-defined) and used the suggestion:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
```

That didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That didn't work because **QSize** is in **PyQt4.Core**!

Try this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

img = QImage(QSize(800, 600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
```

It works for me.